# How Do I Determine Which Tomcat a User's Session Is Pointing To?

Tags: amazon-web-services, session, amazon-ec2, tomcat6, jsessionid

I've recently moved an application to AWS. In our old setup, we were able to figure out which tomcat instance was being hit in the browser by viewing the cookie info in the developerr console and seeing something in the JsessionId/cookie along the lines of "**w1worker1**" and if it was hitting a different Tomcat it would be "**w2worker2**" for example. Is there anyway to determine which Tomcat server is being hit now that I'm on AWS? So far I've yet to see a JsessionID/cookie show anything besides "**w1worker1**". Any information would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why does it matter?  Cloud computing means you have between 1 and a bunch of servers.  It shouldn't matter which machine serves the request.  They will come and go and that's normal.

Comment: It's for troubleshooting purposes. So if we get errors we will have a better idea of which tomcat's log to check